# Nicer pattern for starting tasks and getting their return values

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm implementing some asynchronous work and cant help but feel I'm ending up with a really ugly construction and I'm wondering if and how this could be rewritten to something that 'feels better'.

```
 var tasks = new List<Task>();

 var t1 = new Task<Guid>(() => DoSomeStuff<Xyz>(dtx, e1, M1));
 var t2 = new Task<Guid>(() => DoSomeStuff<Qrs>(dtx, e2, M2));
 var t3 = new Task<Guid>(() => DoSomeStuff<Abc>(dtx, e3, M3));

 tasks.Add(t1);
 tasks.Add(t2);
 tasks.Add(t3);

 tasks.ForEach(x => x.Start());

 Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray<Task>());

 returnDto.t1value = t1.Result;
 returnDto.t2value = t2.Result;
 returnDto.t3value = t3.Result;
```

Variable names have been changed for brevity, there are actually a lot more tasks.
Tasks can all run independently, but all have to be completed before we can continue.

`DoSomeStuff` looks like this:

```
private Guid DoSomeStuff<T>(DependentTransaction dtx, T thing, Func<T, Guid> method)
```

Comment: This might be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Can you use [async-await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be much easier to use `async-await` to wait asynchronously, `Task.WhenAll` to wait for multiple tasks and get their results and `Task.Run` to run `DoSomeStuff` in parallel:

```
Guid[] results = await Task.WhenAll(
    Task.Run(() => DoSomeStuff<Xyz>(dtx, e1, M1)),
    Task.Run(() => DoSomeStuff<Qrs>(dtx, e2, M2)), 
    Task.Run(() => DoSomeStuff<Abc>(dtx, e3, M3)));
```

Comment: I think Func<T, Guid> might be an issue here as it isn't aware of awaitability.

Comment: @Apeiron Do you mean that `DoSomeStuff` returns a `Guid` and not a `Task`? Because `Task.Run` does.

Comment: The point is this: If `DoSomeStuff` is naturally asynchronous you should rewrite it to return a `Task<Guid>` and lose the `Task.Run`. If it's synchronous and you want to parallelize it then use `Task.Run`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm implementing some asynchronous work

It's important to distinguish between *asynchronous* and *parallel* work. Asynchronous work is usually I/O-based, while parallel work uses multiple threads for CPU-bound code.

If your work is asynchronous, then there should be an asynchronous API you can use to make `DoSomeStuff` into an `async` method. Once that is done, it's relatively easy to do concurrent asynchronous work:

```
Guid[] results = await Task.WhenAll(DoSomeStuffAsync<Xyz>(dtx, e1, M1),
    DoSomeStuffAsync<Qrs>(dtx, e2, M2), DoSomeStuffAsync<Abc>(dtx, e3, M3));
```

However, if your work is parallel, then it's best to use the `Parallel` class (or Parallel LINQ):

```
Guid[] results = new Guid[3];
Parallel.Invoke(() => { results[0] = DoSomeStuff<Xyz>(dtx, e1, M1); },
    () => { results[1] = DoSomeStuff<Qrs>(dtx, e2, M2); },
    () => { results[2] = DoSomeStuff<Abc>(dtx, e3, M3); });
```

Comment: In this case the work is definately I.O-bound. DoSomeStuff tries to insert stuff in the database (this in turn is governed by (Dependent) transactions. Ill look into async/await... haven't tries it yet :)